# How do I maintain child SKNode velocities when moving the parent?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I'm working on a game in Swift with SpriteKit. I have a parent node with an SKPhysicsBody and several subnodes with their own physics bodies. All of the subnodes have some velocity relative to the parent node. How do I keep that relative velocity when giving the parent node a velocity? Here's pseudocode to show what I'm trying to do:

```
let parent:SKNode = SKNode()
let child:SKNode = SKNode()
parent.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
child.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
parent.addChild(child)

child.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx: 5, dy: 5)
// child now has velocity
parent.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx: 10, dy:10)
// parent has velocity, but child velocity is still (5,5)
```

How would I get the child velocity to be set such that it maintains a velocity relative to the parent? (e.g. the child's absolute velocity should become (15,15) once the parent is given a velocity of (10,10) so that it maintains (5,5) relative to the parent).
I tried using SKPhysicsJoint but that seems to fix the node and not allow velocity. Any solutions? (I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I'm new to SpriteKit)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the child's velocity to be relative to its parent, add the parent's velocity to the child's constant velocity in the `update` method. For example,

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    child.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(parentNode.physicsBody!.velocity.dx + 5.0, parentNode.physicsBody!.velocity.dy + 5.0)
}
```

BTW, you shouldn't use `parent` as a variable name in Sprite Kit, since it's a property of `SKNode`.

**Update**

You can loop over all children of the parent node with the following.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    for (i, child) in parentNode.children.enumerate() {
        child.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(parentNode.physicsBody!.velocity.dx + velocity[i].dx, parentNode.physicsBody!.velocity.dy + velocity[i].dy)
    }
}
```

`velocity` is an array of `CGVector`s that contains the velocity of each child.

Comment: Yeah, parent isn't my actual variable name, just an example. If there are 50 or 60 children though, doesn't this become inefficient? Is there no way to have an SKPhysicsBody move all of the children as well, like it would if the children were pinned?

Comment: If you don't need the children to move independently of the parent, you can set the `pinned` property of each child's `physicsBody`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I need them to move independently, but if the parent is moved, they maintain relative velocity to the parent. Is it possible to do that with a joint of some sort? If not, I'll use the method you suggested, but I would have to get a list of every node in the parent and do each one individually, which is probably inefficient.

Comment: You can't do that will a physics joint. You can update the velocities of the child nodes by looping over the parent node's `children` array (see my updated answer).